# Checking textbox value in a multipage userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with multiple pages, each with textboxes that I want to make sure are numbers before I dump them back into a worksheet.

I have other normal userforms that do this:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    OnlyNumbers
End Sub

Private Sub OnlyNumbers()

    If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" Then
        With Me.ActiveControl
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
                .Value = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

This works fine, but when I try to do something similar with this multipage userform it doesn't work.

I tried using

`Me.ActiveControl.ActiveControl`

but get a "Object doesn't support this property or method" run time error.  This would work when the textboxes are inside a frame, but it seems like pages are not treated the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this one is tricky. The MultiPage control you can think of as the parent of the controls that sit on top of it. What you need to do is select the MultiPage control first, then select the active control from there.

It looks like:

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value).ActiveControl.Name
```

The Pages property allows you to select which page you want to select. You can get this by using the index of the MultiPage control (the Index starts at 1). Then you can call the ActiveControl and receive the expected control.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was playing around some more and found something that works:
Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.ActiveControl

I think your way would work too though.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, that should work as well. The other approach allows you to select controls that aren't part of the active multi page.